# Why is Clickhouse slower than PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, olap, clickhouse

I want to use Clickhouse as an OLAP and PostgreSQL as an OLTP
database.

The problem is that queries to Clickhouse run slower than on Postgres. The query is as below:

```
select count(id) from {table_name}
```

Here is my table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {table_name} 
        (
            `id` UInt64,
            `label` Nullable(FixedString(50)),
            `query` Nullable(text),
            `creation_datetime` DateTime,
            `offset` UInt64,
            `user_is_first_search` UInt8,
            `user_date_of_start` Date,
            `usage_type` Nullable(FixedString(20)),
            `user_ip` Nullable(FixedString(200)),
            `who_searched_query` Nullable(FixedString(15)),
            `device_type` Nullable(FixedString(20)),
            `device_os` Nullable(FixedString(20)),
            `tab_type` Nullable(FixedString(20)),
            `response_api_type` Nullable(FixedString(20)),
            `total_response_time` Float64,
            `retrieved_instant_answer` Nullable(FixedString(100)),
            `is_relative_instant_answer` UInt8,
            `meta_search_instant_answer_type` Nullable(FixedString(50)),
            `settings_alignment` Nullable(FixedString(20)),
            `settings_safe_search` Nullable(FixedString(30)),
            `settings_search_results_number` Nullable(FixedString(30)),
            `settings_proxy_image_urls` Nullable(FixedString(30)),
            `cache_hit` Nullable(FixedString(20)),
            `net_status` Nullable(FixedString(20)),
            `is_transitional` UInt8
        )
        ENGINE = MergeTree() PARTITION BY creation_datetime ORDER BY (id)
```

I created an index on datetime field in both database and then ran `optimize` query on both. can anyone tell me why Clickhouse is slower than Postgres?

Comment: Wild guess: the count being an attribute of the table in Progresql as opposed to click house?

Comment: No, the table columns is the same in both of them and there is no count field in both @JoopEggen

Comment: If `id` is defined as `not null`, then `count(*)` will actually be slightly faster than `count(id)` in Postgres. Maybe it makes a difference in Clickhouse as well.

Comment: How long does it take in both systems, and what are configurations? I would expect ClickHouse to have a bit of fixed overhead, and it might run slower on such trivial queries. Try something realistic, a bit more complex.

Comment: @MichaelEntin I used in default configuration. Clickhouse has a about 120000 records and Postgresql has 12 million. Clickhouse is very slower than Postgresql. I don't know what I did wrong.

Comment: I just wanted to say: that Postgresql might store the count of a table and hence be faster. `COUNT(DISTINCT id)` again is very slow in comparison.

Comment: @JoopEggen It doesn't.

Comment: It should be `PARTITION BY toYYYYMM(creation_datetime)`

Comment: And obviously you don't need `count(id)` just `count()` because id is not nullable

Comment: Thank you so much @DennyCrane  that was the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the what I did wrong. I should not have made partition by datetime field. I created the table without partition and it got so much faster.

Comment: Partitioning is super important part of Clickhouse tables.

Comment: You should have use toDate(datetime) as partition key

Answer (score 2):

There are ways to shoot your feet with Clickhouse

```sql
create table test ( id Int64, d Date ) Engine=MergeTree Order by id;
insert into test select number, today() from numbers(1e9);

select count() from test;
┌───count()─┐
│ 100000000 │
└───────────┘
1 rows in set. Elapsed: 0.002 sec.

select count(id) from test;
┌─count(id)─┐
│ 100000000 │
└───────────┘
1 rows in set. Elapsed: 0.239 sec. Processed 100.00 million rows, 800.00 MB (418.46 million rows/s., 3.35 GB/s.)


drop table test;

create table test ( id Int64, d Int64 ) Engine=MergeTree partition by (intDiv(d, 10000)) Order by id;
set max_partitions_per_insert_block=0;
insert into test select number, number from numbers(1e8);

select count(id) from test;
┌─count(id)─┐
│ 100000000 │
└───────────┘
1 rows in set. Elapsed: 1.050 sec. Processed 100.00 million rows, 800.00 MB (95.20 million rows/s., 761.61 MB/s.)


select count(d) from test;
┌──count(d)─┐
│ 100000000 │
└───────────┘
1 rows in set. Elapsed: 0.004 sec.
```

Comment: thanks for you reply. I added my table structure to my question. would you please tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: @mohammad You have partitioned table by second, not by month. It should be `PARTITION BY toYYYYMM(creation_datetime)`